# How to go beyond the container while retaining responsive design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-images, responsiveness

i want to build this page but i have a problem which is that i don't know how to force the image out of the bootstrap container while retaining responsive layout, is there anyway i could do that without a ton of absolute positioning for each single device?

**Web Screen Design**

[image]

**IPads and Smaller Screen Designs**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a two-column responsive design that roughly mimics your layout.

It uses the column ordering feature of Bootstrap to swap the order of the text and image blocks on smaller screens.

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.img-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 80px;
}

.div-black {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .img-absolute {
    right: 380px;
  }
  .div-black {
    right: 340px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div clas="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-1 order-lg-2">
      <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim. Duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam. Non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Eros donec ac odio tempor. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat interdum. Morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices. Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem. Pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci. Neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col order-2 order-lg-1">
      <div class="div-black"></div>
      <img class="img-absolute"
           src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```